# Express Session expire time and date are being set wrong

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I have an express session where the maxAge is set to for 1 hour from current time.

```
app.use(
  session({
    secret: 'ASecretValue',
    saveUninitialized: false,
    resave: false,
    cookie: { secure },
    proxy: true,
    path: '/',
    maxAge: new Date(Date.now() + 3600000),
    store: MongoStore.create({ mongoUrl: MONGO_URL }),
  }),
);
```

However when I check in MongoDB, the expire date is set to 2 weeks from current date.

```
_id:"Nm7x9y55z7VZ2e7v_d6PrWlj7EdJKseW"
expires:2021-07-11T13:07:54.446+00:00
session:"{"cookie":{"originalMaxAge":null,"expires":null,"secure":false,"httpOn..."
```

[Link to Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9PqM3.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are three issues here.  First `maxAge` is a number of milliseconds to expiration, NOT a Date object.  Second, the property is `cookie.maxAge` and third, the `secure` property needs a value like this:

```
app.use(
  session({
    secret: 'ASecretValue',
    saveUninitialized: false,
    resave: false,
    cookie: { secure: true, maxAge:  3600000},
    proxy: true,
    path: '/',
    store: MongoStore.create({ mongoUrl: MONGO_URL }),
  }),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out you need to add maxAge to the cookie as well.

```
  app.use(
  session({
    secret: 'ASecretValue',
    saveUninitialized: false,
    resave: false,
    cookie: { secure: true, maxAge: 3600000) },
    proxy: true,
    path: '/',
    maxAge: new Date(Date.now() + 3600000),
    store: MongoStore.create({ mongoUrl: MONGO_URL }),
  }),
);
```

Comment: `maxAge` is a number of ms until expiration from when the cookie is set or updated, not a Date object so there's no way this will work correctly.